# Convert txt file to mixed delimited output using python

Tags: python, text, line, removing-whitespace, delimited

I have quite a messy txt file which I need to convert to a dataframe to use as reference data. An Excerpt is shown below:

> [http://amdc.in2p3.fr/nubase/nubase2016.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvrWu.png)

I've cleaned it up the best I can but to cut a long story short I would like to space delimit most of each line and then fixed delimit the last column. i.e. ignore the spaces in the last section.

[Cleaned Data Text File](https://github.com/Rolleroo/Test/blob/master/NudatClean.txt)

Can anyone point me in the right direction of a resource which can do this? Not sure if Pandas copes with this?

Kenny

P.S. I have found some great resources to clean up the multiple whitespaces and replace the line breaks. Sorry can't find the original reference, so see attached.

```
fin = open("Input.txt", "rt")
fout = open("Ouput.txt", "wt")

for line in fin:
      fout.write(re.sub(' +', ' ', line).strip() + "\n")
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is always recommended to include an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, if you have found the solution to your own question, you might as well post it as an answer.

Comment: Hi @rotton, I am still looking for something which can do this.

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111690/python-read-formatted-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what i would do is very simple, i would clean up the data as much as possible and then convert it to a csv file, because they are easy to use. An then i would step by step load it into a pandas dataframe and change if it needed.

```
with open("NudatClean.txt") as f:
    text=f.readlines()

import csv
with open('dat.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for i in text:
        l=i.split(' ')
        row=[]
        for a in l:
            if a!='':
                row.append(a)
        print(row)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

That should to the job for the beginning. But I don't know what you want remove exactly so I think the rest should be pretty clear.

Comment: Hi @SebNik, I have stripped it down as much as I can, I've added a link to the cleaned file. I'd like to produce the csv file automatically but need to use the mixed delimiting i.e. space and fixed delimited, to get a sensible csv format.

Comment: Okay i will see what i can do.

Comment: Should be done now, if that answers your question glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to write a csv file but only delimits on the spaces. I've decided to split the file into two as the application will allow different tables.

Comment: Okay sounds good, if your question is then answered please mark it at solved, so that it is clear for the system.

Answer (score 0):

The way I managed to do this was split the csv into two parts then recombine. Not particularly elegant but did the job I needed.

[Split by Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50016607/split-csv-by-columns)